# view_helper time_field without am/pm and with seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionviewhelper

Is there any standard form input in rails 4 with a mask to receive time in the following format: mm:ss? where the minutes section may be greater than 60.

I'm trying with the view_helper time_field, but I couldn't find a way to remove the am/pm and to have the seconds section.

Thanks in advance!